# Error installing Fade In Pro on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: 19.10

I tried to install **Fade In Professional Screenwriting Software** version 3.0.625 using GDebi. It failed, throwing this error message:

```
Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0)
```

Can anyone tell me how to proceed? Thanks. My script is waiting!

-Blair Peery

Comment: Remove the software you just tried to install, then install **libpango-1.0-0** and try again.

Comment: I tried to install libpango-1.0-0 with these commands in the terminal:

`sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libpango-1.0-0`

The second command said I already had Pango:

`libpango-1.0-0 is already the newest version (1.42.4-7).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 64 not upgraded.`

Any ideas?

-Blair